# Echo all results from mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to create a function that will query a database and output all the results from the array. For some reason it is only displaying one result.

here is the function

```
function reguser_list() {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1");
$reguser_names = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$list_names = implode(', ', $reguser_names);

echo $reguser_names;
}
```

there are currently 2 users in the database that are active but this only display one name how can I get it to display both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to iterate the result of `mysql_query`, eg.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo $row['user_name'];
}
```

---

since i see that you want to concatenate the result by separating it with comma, you can directly do it in `MySQL` buy using `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_name) as UserName FROM users WHERE active = 1
```

in `PHP`,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_name) as UserName FROM users WHERE active = 1");
$reguser_names = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$list_names = $reguser_names['UserName'];
```

The default limit of [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is `1024`.

If you want change the value of the variable the syntax is:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
// where val is an unsigned integer
```

[more on this link..](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Beware of the relatively low default length limit on `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: @J W well i would prefer to have them displayed in an unordered list. so would I use something like `return '<ul><li>' . implode('<li></li>', $row) . '</li></ul>';`

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to stick with `ext/mysql`, you need to use a `while` loop.  `PDOStatement` has a very nice `fetchAll` method that can essentially be substituted for what you have.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=?', 'user', 'pass');
//If `active` is 1 or 0 only, you don't need the `= 1`
echo implode(', ', $pdo->query("SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE active = 1")
    ->fetchAll());
```

Comment: I have a connect.php that already connects me to the database. could i not still use that instead of the `new PDO(creds)`?

Comment: @zachstarnes no you can't because `PDO` will not create a "global" connection (which is frankly not great practice).  You can however wrap `PDO` with another class that includes the credentials and just create that class `class DB { public function __construct() { return new PDO(credentials); }}` `$pdo = new DB;`

Comment: Okay. I have multiple functions that use `mysql_query` so each time I do a query I have to do what you did above? (just making changes to the `pdo->query`) so if i change the username or password used to access the database I have to change it on all of them?

Comment: @zachstarnes that will work for now, but you should use properly parameterized queries in the cases where the queries require input

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop when fetching from the db.

**You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code** ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)), they are [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Use [PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_* are deprecated**

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo $row['user_name'];
    }
```